# How does jackson know the type of generic objects in Java?

Tags: java, json, generics, reflection, jackson

I use Jackson to parse strings to Java objects. For example Java object is:

```
class MyObject {
  MyField myField;
  List<MyListField> myList;
}
```

In runtime I have info about myField and can instantiate it via reflection:

```
myObject.myField = MyField.newInstance()
```

In runtime I don't have info about generic type of myList, and I can not fill it with MyListField instances. How does Jackson do it?

Comment: As a guess, it calls [`Field.getGenericType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getGenericType()) to look at the field declaration, rather than its runtime value.

Comment: @AndyTurner good guess, and that's exactly the case. Resolution itself is done similar to how ClassMate (https://github.com/FasterXML/java-classmate) does it.